# codeigniter pagination next page 404 not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

Index page are working well but when i click page 2 it show 404 page not found.

Controller

```
public function index() {
   $config = array();
   $config['base_url'] = base_url('admin/booking');
   $total_row = $this->booking_m->record_count();
   $config["total_rows"] = $total_row;
   $config["per_page"] = 1;
   $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
   $config['num_links'] = $total_row;
   $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
   $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
   $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
   $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';

   $this->pagination->initialize($config);

   if($this->uri->segment(3)){
     $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ;
  }
  else{
    $page = 1;
 }


  $data["info"] = $this->booking_m->fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page);
  $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
  $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links );


  $this->load->view('admin/booking/index',$data);}
```

Page url is http://127.0.0.1/admin/booking/1 it work.

http://127.0.0.1/admin/booking/2 // Not found error

Model

```
public function fetch_data($limit, $id) {
$this->db->limit($limit);
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get("booking");
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
    }

    return $data;
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the route if not try

```
$route['admin/booking/(:any)'] = 'controllername/function/$1';
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=routes

Your base url should look something like

```
| http://example.com/
|
| WARNING: You MUST set this value!
|
| If it is not set, then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol and path
| your installation, but due to security concerns the hostname will be set
| to $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] if available, or localhost otherwise.
| The auto-detection mechanism exists only for convenience during
| development and MUST NOT be used in production!

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
```

If you have the IP address in your url then some links may not work that why is good to set url and use localhost instead of IP

Also make sure you follow the ucfirst way for class and file names as explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a config. Place it in config

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
```

instead of this config `$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;` and try

Comment: Yes I change base url $config['base_url'] = base_url('l0gadmin/booking/index'); and your code. now i ok page are working well but page 2 not show data. please check my model function.

Comment: so what is your problem now?

Answer (score 0):

By using inspect->element check the url to which the second page is redirecting..